# Python マストドンで特定のキーワードを含むトゥートを取得する

Tags: python, mastodon

マストドンの特定のキーワードを含むトゥートを取得したいです。
特定のインスタンスのタイムラインはMastodon.timelineメソッドで取得可能ですが、
取得したデータから特定のキーワードを含むトゥートを検索するのは大量のトゥートを取得しなければならず、効率が悪い気がします。
何か良い方法があれば教えてください。

追記
下のコードを実行したのですが、空データが返ってきました。
何か設定が間違っているのでしょうか。

```
serch_word = '茶'
utftext =  serch_word.encode('utf-8')
urlencode = urllib.parse.quote(utftext, '')
result = mastodon.search('https://mstdn.jp/api/v1/search?q=' + urlencode)
print(result)
```

結果

```
{'hashtags': [], 'accounts': [], 'statuses': []}
```

一応念のために確認なのですが、私の使っているパッケージは下記のコマンドでpipを通じてインストールしました。こちらのAPI（/api/v1/search）とこのパッケージAPIとは別物なのでしょうか。
pip install Mastodon.py

キーワード検索、全文検索が有効化されているかを知る方法はわからないですが、mstdn.jpはこちらのURLで検索可能になっていたため、検索が有効と判断しました。ただ、今後のためにキーワード検索、全文検索が有効のインスタンスかどうか判断する方法をご存知の方は教えてください。

Comment: `mstdn.jp` というインスタンスで全文検索が有効なことを確認していますか？ `mastodon.search` の部分は何かのライブラリを使用したコードですか？ `search` というメソッドの引数に API の URL を渡すというのは、いかにも奇妙だと思いますが、この使い方は何かで確認しましたか？

Comment: キーワード検索、全文検索が有効化されているかを知る方法はわからないですが、mstdn.jpはこちらのURLで検索可能になっていたため、検索が有効と判断しました。http://www.mastodonsearch.jp/　URLは参考ページにURLを指定するように書いてありましたのでそれに従いました。

Comment: mastodonsearch.jp はAPで独自にTootを収集している外部サービスで、mstdn.jpの提供する検索APIとは一切関係ありません。(またjpには指摘されているよう有効化されていなかった気がします)

Comment: ついでにマストドン全文検索ですが、一般公開ではないものの検索APIを提供されているようなのでそちらを利用することも可能かも。 https://mstdn.jp/@mastodonsearch/29458658

Answer (score 1, accepted):

検索用のAPIがあるようです。実際に利用するには事前にOAuth2 クライアントの登録、アクセストークンの発行などが必要になるそうです。

```
https://${MASTODON_HOST}/api/v1/search?q=${keyword}
```

参考：[API - Search | tootsuite/documentation](https://github.com/tootsuite/documentation/blob/master/Using-the-API/API.md#search)

Comment: （補足ですがMastodonのキーワード検索、全文検索が有効化されてる一部のインスタンスのみで利用可能なので注意が必要です）

Comment: 実行はできました。しかし、キーワードにいくつかのデータを指定したのですが、空データが返ってきます。どこか間違っているのでしょうか。

Comment: もう1点補足です。Mastodonの検索APIですが、上流の実装では自分のTootや自分のリアクションしたTootのみが検索対象になります。(インスタンスによってはカスタマイズして全Tootを対象にしているものもなくはないですが)